# check if a word/letter is contained in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I cant find a way to search for a letter/string within a substring. the objective is to create an alert if the string is found. Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/1rawcotx/2/

```js
function validate() {
  if (string.indexOf('worlds') > -1) {
    alert("word found");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="string">
  worlds and some other text
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="validate()">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM elements don't have an `indexOf`, but in your example, `string` is a DOM element because you're using the *automatic global* created by giving your `div` `id="string"`.

To get the contents of the `div`, you'd use its [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) or [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) properties.

I also wouldn't advocate using automatic globals (although they're in the spec now), because there are too many conflicting globals out there. Instead, I would explicitly use `getElementById`:

```js
function validate() {
  if (document.getElementById("string").innerHTML.indexOf('worlds') > -1) {
    alert("word found");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="string">
  worlds and some other text
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="validate()">click me</button>
```

Comment: whats the significance of '> -1' ?

Comment: @RolandWarburton: It's from *your* code. :-) `indexOf` returns the index at which the substring is found, or `-1` if it isn't found. Using `> -1` is a common way to check whether it was found, although I typically use `!== -1`. Either is fine. Another option, on modern JavaScript engines, is to use `includes` rather than `indexOf`, but some obsolete engines still in use (such as in IE8) don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the DOM element `innerHTML` by calling `document.getElementById` or `document.querySelector`

You can also directly use [`String#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
const divValue = document.querySelector('#string').innerHTML;
function validate() {
  if (divValue.includes('worlds')) {
    alert("word found");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="string">
  worlds and some other text
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="validate()">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define [`string`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) variable first, using `document.getElementById('string').innerHTML`

```js
function validate() {
var string =document.getElementById('string').innerHTML;
  if (string.indexOf('worlds') > -1) {
    alert("word found");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="string">
  worlds and some other text
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="validate()">click me</button>
```

Comment: *"string is undefined variable"* Actually, it isn't in the OP's code; it's an automatic global (shudder).